# How to fix permalink structure in WordPress for the upcoming events and photo gallery?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

We are using a calendar plugin to display upcoming events for a WordPress website.

The individual event page has the default URL structure as https://www.example.com/event/event-name-1/

Following are the settings on our client's website:
The blog page is this: https://www.example.com/blog-page/
The permalink structure is: https://www.example.com/blog-page//%category%/%postname%/

The event page also follows this permalink structure so the events URLs are: https://www.example.com/blog-page/event/event-name-1/

I want these URLs should be https://www.example.com/event/event-name-1/ (meaning, event pages shouldn't list under blog-page)

I tried following:

Setup the custom structure as /%category%/%postname%/ and added 
category base: /blog-page/

This fixed issue with the event's URLs; but then it breaks the permalink structure for the blog posts.

I am getting the same issue with the photo-gallery as well.

How to fix this? Is there any plugin available?

Comment: Which calendar plugin you use ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix to this issue.

It is related to WordPress Custom Post Type and [this article on WPBeginner](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-change-custom-post-type-permalinks-in-wordpress/) helps to fix it.